# Extracting working correlation matrix from a geeglm object produced using geepack

Tags: r

**tl;dr**

How does one extract the working correlation matrix from a `geeglm` object produced by `geepack` in R?

---

**Longer question**

I use `geepack::geeglm` to analyze longitudinal data for my job. I like the `geepack` package because it interfaces nicely with other r packages, like `jtools`, `broom`, and `gtsummary` (which relies heavily on `broom`). However, occasionally I find it useful to examine the working correlation matrix produced from my GEE analysis and I've yet to figure out how to extract the working correlation matrix from a `geeglm` object. Comparatively, the `gee::gee` function stores the working correlation matrix as part of the output, making it very easily accessible.

Consider the following:

```
# Loading packages
library(geepack, gee)

# Loading ohio data from geepack
data(ohio)

# Fitting several models using geepack::geeglm()
mod.1 = geeglm(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'exchangeable')
mod.2 = geeglm(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'independence')
mod.3 = geeglm(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'unstructured')
mod.4 = geeglm(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'ar1')

# Fitting several models using gee::gee()
mod.a = gee(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'exchangeable')
mod.b = gee(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'independence')
mod.c = gee(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'unstructured')
mod.d = gee(resp ~ factor(smoke) + age, data = ohio, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = 'AR-M', Mv = 1)
```

So far, I've found that the `$geese$alpha` stored within the `geeglm` output returns some of the info that I need...

```
# Extracting the exchangeable correlation structure
> mod.1$geese$alpha
alpha 
0.354 

> mod.a$working.correlation
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 1.000 0.354 0.354 0.354
[2,] 0.354 1.000 0.354 0.354
[3,] 0.354 0.354 1.000 0.354
[4,] 0.354 0.354 0.354 1.000

# Extracting the unstructured correlation structure
> mod.3$geese$alpha
alpha.1:2 alpha.1:3 alpha.1:4 alpha.2:3 alpha.2:4 alpha.3:4 
    0.350     0.308     0.303     0.470     0.319     0.376 

> mod.c$working.correlation
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 1.000 0.350 0.308 0.303
[2,] 0.350 1.000 0.470 0.319
[3,] 0.308 0.470 1.000 0.376
[4,] 0.303 0.319 0.376 1.000
```

However, when I attempt to extract an `AR-1` correlation structure, things get confusing...

```
# Extracting the AR-1 correlation structure
> mod.4$geese$alpha
alpha 
0.491
 
> mod.d$working.correlation
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]   [,4]
[1,] 1.0000 0.399 0.159 0.0635
[2,] 0.3990 1.000 0.399 0.1592
[3,] 0.1592 0.399 1.000 0.3990
[4,] 0.0635 0.159 0.399 1.0000
```

Now, the `summary()` for both `mod.4` and `mod.d` (not shown) indicate that the models aren't equivalent even though they are both supposed to use an `AR-1` correlation structure. I'm not entirely sure why this is, though I suppose it could be a difference on the backend that isn't immediately apparent in the documentation. That said, even if they aren't equivalent, if `$geese$alpha` indeed returned elements of the working correlation structure then one would presume that for an 'AR-1' corstr there would still be more elements than what is returned from `mod.4$geese$alpha` so I am at a loss.

Any insight on a straight-forward method for extracting the correlation matrix from a `geeglm` object, akin to what can be extracted from a model fit using `gee::gee()`, would be appreciated!